# Converted POST FromBody to HttpRequestMessage - Need to Desearialize Body of Request

Tags: c#, rest, serialization, httprequest, deserialization

I have working REST code that accepts POST messages using FromBody.  The parameter received is the object I need to work with.  Now, I need to examine the authorization in the header.  I think have this figured out by switching the parameter from the object to an HttpRequestMessage.  Of course, now the content of the message must be converted to the original object and I'm having difficulty figuring it out.

Here is the original method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] CardStatusRoot cardStatus)
    {
        try
        {
            if (cardStatus == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Card data not provided");
            }
            if (cardStatus.Data.TransactionType.ToLower() == "card")
            {
                //... Process;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            try
            {
                // Log the failure to fund the card
            }
            catch { }

            return InternalServerError();
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

New Code, using HttpRequestMessage:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(HttpRequestMessage request)   
    {
        // Get the authentication from the header
        var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
        var authValue = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter));
        var validAuthorization = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidKey"];

        if (authValue != validAuthorization)
        {
            return BadRequest("Not Authorized");
        }

        // This does NOT compile - Need help converting request.Content to a CardStatusRoot object
        CardStatusRoot cardStatus = (CardStatusRoot)request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

     ... Same as first method
    }
```

How do I convert the content of the request to a CardStatusRoot object?

Comment: you can have both parameters like: `Post([FromBody] CardStatusRoot cardStatus, HttpRequestMessage request)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ApiController` has access to the current request via the `Request` property.

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] CardStatusRoot cardStatus) {
    try {
        HttpRequestMessage request = this.Request;
        if (cardStatus == null) {
            return BadRequest("Card data not provided");
        }
        if (cardStatus.Data.TransactionType.ToLower() == "card") {
            //... Process;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        try {
            // Log the failure to fund the card
        }
        catch { }

        return InternalServerError();
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

That said, this question feels more like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

You should be looking into

[Authentication Filters in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters)

[Global Error Handling in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/)

Comment: Thanks!  I was hoping there was an easy answer.  I take from your provided links that you don't like my error handling methodology?

Comment: @MarkBonafe Error handling and logging in Asp.net Web API is a cross-cutting concern. You controllers should as lean as possible. The framework offers many extension points to add in that functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the previous signature method to compute with data. You can directly access headers value like this

```
Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter
```

Where `Request` is the object provided in `ApiController` for each request.